# How to query between two tables using IF(condition, tableA, tableB) in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to do a query based on a logic condition to query between two tables.

```
select *
from if(1>2, tableA, tableB)
```

`1>2` above is simply one example logic test, it can be any logic value.

But `if` function in Hive cannot work within `FROM` above. Any idea how?

Comment: try case when in hive for logics

Comment: nope. case when cannot work to select one table between two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
select * from tableA where 1>2
union all
select * from tableB where 1<2;
```

Which query will be running depends on the WHERE condition.